# Displaying Lotus Notes documents in a specific order on a web Page

Tags: lotus-notes

We have a web site in which it is built using Lotus Notes. This site allows users to submit their applications for employment.  On the initial screen the user selects the location and/or area of interest they are interested in.  From their selection, a listing of the various positions available are displayed.

The issue that we are having is trying to get the listing to display the various positions in some type of order.  The listing is displayed using a view.
Within this view, there are 4 columns.  In the first column, the job title is displayed.  In the second column, is the shift, the third column is the area of interest and the last column is the reference number. In the first column of the view, this is the value for the column title - "Job Title"

Below is the formula for the column value:

ThisDB := @ReplaceSubstring(@ReplaceSubstring(@Subset(@DbName; -1);" ";"+");"\";"/");
Temp := "" ;

"" + temp +  jobTitle + ""

When this is displayed, it is displayed in order by the document ID, is there a way of getting this to be displayed by the area of interest?  The area of interest would appear as "Purchasing", "Accounting", "Sales", etc.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Jean

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the view in Notes Designer and double-click on one of the column headers to open the properties. You can set a sort order in the properties dialog for the area of interest column, and make sure no other columns are sorted.

Alternatively, you can add a hidden column just for sorting as the first column from the left. That column can be the same value as area of interest (or anything else you need to sort by) but it won't display when the view is rendered.

Comment: This will work if the application is narrowing down the selection using a Show Single Category view. It would not work if the view is actually displaying a FT search result, but then again I don't think that would be ordered by docid so I doubt that's what's really going on. My point, though, is that we may need more info about the app.

Comment: Here is additional detail concerning this app.... hopefully something will stand out as to why the sort isn't working.  I have tried the column sort in the view, but that hasn't worked.   I may have to send this detail in two parts..

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue - within the formula we were using "searchview" and with the sort order for this defaults to "relevance".  By adding the "searchorder=4" option users the designated column we have set as the sort order for the listing. Thank you for your comments and hope this helps someone else.